# Python Boto3 for ECS Help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to list all the clusters in my AWS ECS account. I have approximately 13 Clusters running.

The below code prints only one cluster, whereas I want to print all the clusters. Is there a `for` loop which I can use?

Below prints only one cluster:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ecs')
response = client.list_clusters(
    maxResults=50
)
print(response)
```

Below for looping doesn't work and throws an error

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ecs')
for response in client.list_cluster():
    print(response)
```

Any lead would highly be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is you are querying the API for the wrong AWS region. What region are your ECS clusters in? What region do you have set as a default in `~/.aws/credentials` or `~/.aws/config`?

Comment: that would be us-east-2

Comment: us-east-2 for both?

Comment: that is the only region in this account which I use with all the 13 clusters

Comment: Does it work if you do `client = boto3.client('ecs', region_name='us-east-2')`?

Comment: Error I get 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python1.py", line 12, in <module>
    for response in client.list_cluster():
  File "/home/ubu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 526, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'ECS' object has no attribute 'list_cluster'`

Comment: You're missing the `s` in `list_clusters()`

Comment: wow, that's a relief.

I added the `s` in the `list_clusters()`

but the output is see is something like below.

`python3 python1.py
clusterArns
ResponseMetadata`

Whereas I should get the cluster description as output ?

Comment: No, for descriptions you need `describe_clusters()`

Comment: but those are not even the cluster names. the cluster names that i have are prod_nam & eu_nam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [list_clusters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.list_clusters) api, the response syntax is:

```
 Response Syntax

{
    'clusterArns': [
        'string',
    ],
    'nextToken': 'string'
}
```

which means you'll get back a list(`[]`) of [ARNs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) which are unique resource identifiers in AWS.

Use [describe_clusters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_clusters) api to then then get a description, as @jordanm said:

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ecs', region_name='us-east-2')
clusters = client.list_clusters(
    maxResults=50
)
clusters_arns = clusters['clusterArns']

clusters_descriptions = client.describe_clusters(
    clusters=clusters_arns
)

for cluster in clusters_descriptions['clusters']:
    print(cluster['clusterName'])
```

result is something like:

```
prod_nam
eu_nam
someothercluster
```